# Update is not working due to Malformed entry error

Tags: 16.04, command-line

[image]

[image]

[image]

`sudo apt-get update` is not working, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a related file, but it's the wrong one. Your error clearly states that the problem is line one in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list` which according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli) should be `deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main` for 14.04 and `deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ xenial main` for 16.04. if the line you have exactly matches for your distribution you should [report a bug.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) If not, fix it with your favorite editor.